# org.hibernate.MappingException when integrating hibernate with CAS

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, cas

My university is working on setting up CAS. Currently, I am working on getting hibernate integrated with CAS so that CAS can connect to a database and have been following this guide:
https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Configuring

The full stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servicesManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-configuration/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'serviceRegistryDao' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceRegistryDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: CasPersistence] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:616)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1003)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:907)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized_aroundBody0(SafeContextLoaderListener.java:62)
at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized_aroundBody1$advice(SafeContextLoaderListener.java:44)
at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(SafeContextLoaderListener.java:1)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceRegistryDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: CasPersistence] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: CasPersistence] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
... 38 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: CasPersistence] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
... 45 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: RegisteredServiceImpl, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(a_name)]
at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:304)
at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:288)
at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:216)
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:467)
at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:268)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1287)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1718)
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:76)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
... 51 more
```

My serviceRegistryDao and dataSource beans:

```
<bean id="serviceRegistryDao" class="org.jasig.cas.services.JpaServiceRegistryDaoImpl"
p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />
<!-- This is the EntityManagerFactory configuration for Hibernate -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>


<bean
    id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    p:url="jdbc:sqlserver://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx;databaseName=XXX"
    p:password="XXXXX"
    p:username="XXXXX" />
```

I'll also put my persistence.xml file in here, but I haven't changed it at all from the default:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="CasPersistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>org.jasig.cas.services.RegisteredServiceImpl</class>
    <class>org.jasig.cas.ticket.TicketGrantingTicketImpl</class>
    <class>org.jasig.cas.ticket.ServiceTicketImpl</class>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

RegisteredServiceImpl.java (from cas-server-core-3.4.10.jar which can be explored here: http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/inspect/org/jasig/cas/cas-server-core/3.4.10/cas-server-core-3.4.10-sources.jar

```
/*
 * Copyright 2007 The JA-SIG Collaborative. All rights reserved. See license
 * distributed with this file and available online at
 * http://www.uportal.org/license.html
 */
package org.jasig.cas.services;

import java.sql.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;

import javax.persistence.GenerationType;

import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder;Class search for 'org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder'
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringStyle;Class search for 'org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringStyle'
import org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionOfElements;Class search for 'org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionOfElements'
import org.hibernate.annotations.IndexColumn;Class search for 'org.hibernate.annotations.IndexColumn'
import org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.Service;Class search for 'org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.Service'
import org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher;Class search for 'org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher'
import org.springframework.util.Assert;Class search for 'org.springframework.util.Assert'
import org.springframework.util.PathMatcher;Class search for 'org.springframework.util.PathMatcher'

/**
 * Mutable implementation of a RegisteredService.
 * 
 * @author Scott Battaglia
 * @version $Revision: 22918 $ $Date: 2011-02-06 23:02:50 -0500 (Sun, 06 Feb 2011) $
 * @since 3.1
 */
@Entity
public class RegisteredServiceImpl
    implements RegisteredService, Comparable<RegisteredService> {

/** Unique Id for serialization. */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5136788302682868276L;

private static final PathMatcher PATH_MATCHER = new AntPathMatcher();

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id = -1;


@CollectionOfElements(targetElement = String.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "rs_attributes")
@Column(name = "a_name", nullable = false)
@IndexColumn(name = "a_id")
private List<String> allowedAttributes = new ArrayList<String>();

private String description;

private String serviceId;

private String name;

private String theme;

private boolean allowedToProxy = true;

private boolean enabled = true;

private boolean ssoEnabled = true;

private boolean anonymousAccess = false;

private boolean ignoreAttributes = false;

@Column(name = "evaluation_order", nullable = false)
private int evaluationOrder;

public boolean isAnonymousAccess() {
    return this.anonymousAccess;
}

public void setAnonymousAccess(final boolean anonymousAccess) {
    this.anonymousAccess = anonymousAccess;
}

public List<String> getAllowedAttributes() {
    return this.allowedAttributes;
}

public long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return this.description;
}

public String getServiceId() {
    return this.serviceId;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public String getTheme() {
    return this.theme;
}

public boolean isAllowedToProxy() {
    return this.allowedToProxy;
}

public boolean isEnabled() {
    return this.enabled;
}

public boolean isSsoEnabled() {
    return this.ssoEnabled;
}

public boolean matches(final Service service) {
    return service != null && PATH_MATCHER.match(this.serviceId.toLowerCase(), service.getId().toLowerCase());
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof RegisteredServiceImpl)) return false;

    RegisteredServiceImpl that = (RegisteredServiceImpl) o;

    if (allowedToProxy != that.allowedToProxy) return false;
    if (anonymousAccess != that.anonymousAccess) return false;
    if (enabled != that.enabled) return false;
    if (evaluationOrder != that.evaluationOrder) return false;
    if (ignoreAttributes != that.ignoreAttributes) return false;
    if (ssoEnabled != that.ssoEnabled) return false;
    if (allowedAttributes != null ? !allowedAttributes.equals(that.allowedAttributes) : that.allowedAttributes != null)
        return false;
    if (description != null ? !description.equals(that.description) : that.description != null) return false;
    if (name != null ? !name.equals(that.name) : that.name != null) return false;
    if (serviceId != null ? !serviceId.equals(that.serviceId) : that.serviceId != null) return false;
    if (theme != null ? !theme.equals(that.theme) : that.theme != null) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = allowedAttributes != null ? allowedAttributes.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (description != null ? description.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (serviceId != null ? serviceId.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (theme != null ? theme.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (allowedToProxy ? 1 : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (enabled ? 1 : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (ssoEnabled ? 1 : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (anonymousAccess ? 1 : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (ignoreAttributes ? 1 : 0);
    result = 31 * result + evaluationOrder;
    return result;
}

public void setAllowedAttributes(final List<String> allowedAttributes) {
    if (allowedAttributes == null) {
        this.allowedAttributes = new ArrayList<String>();
    } else {
        this.allowedAttributes = allowedAttributes;
    }
}

public void setAllowedToProxy(final boolean allowedToProxy) {
    this.allowedToProxy = allowedToProxy;
}

public void setDescription(final String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public void setEnabled(final boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

public void setServiceId(final String id) {
    this.serviceId = id;
}

public void setId(final long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setName(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setSsoEnabled(final boolean ssoEnabled) {
    this.ssoEnabled = ssoEnabled;
}

public void setTheme(final String theme) {
    this.theme = theme;
}

public boolean isIgnoreAttributes() {
    return this.ignoreAttributes;
}

public void setIgnoreAttributes(final boolean ignoreAttributes) {
    this.ignoreAttributes = ignoreAttributes;
}

public void setEvaluationOrder(final int evaluationOrder) {
    this.evaluationOrder = evaluationOrder;
}

public int getEvaluationOrder() {
    return this.evaluationOrder;
}

public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    final RegisteredServiceImpl registeredServiceImpl = new RegisteredServiceImpl();

    registeredServiceImpl.setAllowedAttributes(this.allowedAttributes);
    registeredServiceImpl.setAllowedToProxy(this.allowedToProxy);
    registeredServiceImpl.setDescription(this.description);
    registeredServiceImpl.setEnabled(this.enabled);
    registeredServiceImpl.setId(this.id);
    registeredServiceImpl.setName(this.name);
    registeredServiceImpl.setServiceId(this.serviceId);
    registeredServiceImpl.setSsoEnabled(this.ssoEnabled);
    registeredServiceImpl.setTheme(this.theme);
    registeredServiceImpl.setAnonymousAccess(this.anonymousAccess);
    registeredServiceImpl.setIgnoreAttributes(this.ignoreAttributes);
    registeredServiceImpl.setEvaluationOrder(this.evaluationOrder);

    return registeredServiceImpl;
}


public int compareTo(final RegisteredService other) {
    final int result = this.evaluationOrder - other.getEvaluationOrder();
    if (result == 0) {
        return (int)(this.id - other.getId());
    }
    return result;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    final ToStringBuilder toStringBuilder = new ToStringBuilder(this, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE);
    toStringBuilder.append("id", this.id);
    toStringBuilder.append("name", this.name);
    toStringBuilder.append("description", this.description);
    toStringBuilder.append("serviceId", this.serviceId);
    toStringBuilder.append("attributes", this.allowedAttributes.toArray());

    return toStringBuilder.toString();
}
}
```

Any help/advice would be much appreciated. Let me know if there is any other info I should post.

Comment: publish the hibernate mapping for class **RegisteredServiceImpl**.

Comment: I have added the mapping for RegisteredServiceImpl as requested.

Comment: In case anyone comes looking at this later, we were never able to solve it; instead, we just manually listed the services in the serviceRegistryDao bean in deployerConfigContext.xml. However, if I were to make a guess as to what might have been causing the error, I would say it has to do with the fact that I'm working on a server with limited access, so it was probably needing to pull something from the internet and was unable to. Better luck to anyone else with this error!

Answer (score 0):

I've recently updated my CAS to version 3.4.11, however this shouldn't change the aplicability of my solution.

The following shows my datasource definition in the deployerConfigContext.xml

```
<bean
    id="dataSource"
    class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    p:driverClass="${database.driverClass}"
    p:jdbcUrl="${database.url}"
    p:user="${database.user}"
    p:password="${database.password}"
    p:initialPoolSize="${database.pool.minSize}"
    p:minPoolSize="${database.pool.minSize}"
    p:maxPoolSize="${database.pool.maxSize}"
    p:maxIdleTimeExcessConnections="${database.pool.maxIdleTime}"
    p:checkoutTimeout="${database.pool.maxWait}"
    p:acquireIncrement="${database.pool.acquireIncrement}"
    p:acquireRetryAttempts="${database.pool.acquireRetryAttempts}"
    p:acquireRetryDelay="${database.pool.acquireRetryDelay}"
    p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="${database.pool.idleConnectionTestPeriod}"
    p:preferredTestQuery="${database.pool.connectionHealthQuery}"
    />
```

and the corrisponding fields in the cas.properties

```
# == Basic database connection pool configuration ==
database.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
database.driverClass=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
database.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server.uni.it:52112/CAS;instance=zzzzz;domain=UNI
database.user=xxxxx
database.password=yyyyy
database.pool.minSize=6
database.pool.maxSize=18
# Maximum amount of time to wait in ms for a connection to become
# available when the pool is exhausted
database.pool.maxWait=10000
# Amount of time in seconds after which idle connections
# in excess of minimum size are pruned.
database.pool.maxIdleTime=120
# Number of connections to obtain on pool exhaustion condition.
# The maximum pool size is always respected when acquiring
# new connections.
database.pool.acquireIncrement=6
# == Connection testing settings ==
# Period in s at which a health query will be issued on idle
# connections to determine connection liveliness.
database.pool.idleConnectionTestPeriod=30
# Query executed periodically to test health
database.pool.connectionHealthQuery=select 1
# == Database recovery settings ==
# Number of times to retry acquiring a _new_ connection
# when an error is encountered during acquisition.
database.pool.acquireRetryAttempts=5
# Amount of time in ms to wait between successive aquire retry attempts.
database.pool.acquireRetryDelay=2000
```

My persistence.xml (the Lock is just needed if you implement the locking strategy)

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="CasPersistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>org.jasig.cas.services.RegisteredServiceImpl</class>
        <class>org.jasig.cas.ticket.TicketGrantingTicketImpl</class>
        <class>org.jasig.cas.ticket.ServiceTicketImpl</class>
        <class>org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.support.JpaLockingStrategy$Lock</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And last but not least the corrisponding pom.xml entries

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
    <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>${c3p0.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
    <version>${sqlserver-connector.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Maybe it solves by using this SQL-Server driver

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue. There are 2 reason why this error flashed on the screen.

1. Your .jar file may not be compatible with each other.
2. The .jar file added in the classpath might be incompatible with the jdk's version.
3. There might be the case that you had added same jar but with different version.

Out off above 3 mentioned reasons looks like you are having jdk compatibility with the jar's.